# Why does TestComplete keep changing status image name

Tags: logging, automated-tests, testcomplete

I want to parse TestComplele 7 logs programmatically. Specifically, I want to get names and statuses (success\failure\warning) of each test.

According to manual, I use the following command to get test run logs:

```
Log["SaveResultsAs"] ("PathToMyFolder", 1);
```

This creates a bunch of files and folders, including XMLs which can be parsed by my script.
Here is an example of such an XML:

```xml
<ProjectLog>
  <ProjectLogItem id="0" pid="-1" nety="False">
    <Status>805039D.gif</Status>
    <No>1</No>
    <Name><![CDATA[Script Test Log [cTaStoring\cTaStoring_Start]]]></Name>
    <StartTime>13.04.2012 12:26:15</StartTime>
    <EndTime>13.04.2012 12:27:47</EndTime>
    <RunTime>0:01:32</RunTime>
    <Details></Details>
    <Messages/>
   </ProjectLogItem>
   <ProjectLogItem id="1" pid="-1" nety="False">
    <Status>905039C.gif</Status>
    <No>2</No>
    <Name><![CDATA[AutomaticStoring]]></Name>
    <StartTime>13.04.2012 12:27:47</StartTime>
    <EndTime>13.04.2012 12:30:42</EndTime>
    <RunTime>0:02:55</RunTime>
    <Details></Details>
    <Messages/>
   </ProjectLogItem>
</ProjectLog>
```

As you can see, I can get almost everything I want, but the most valuable piece of data, the status of a test is written as a file name of a picture showing the corresponding icon! E.g. 805039D.gif contains a checkmark and 905039C.gif contains an exclamation mark.

It would be easy to hardcode these names in my scripts, but the problem is that they change constantly!

**Questions**:

1. Why have they decided to use image names instead of some enumeration
   to output statuses?
2. Why on earth do icons change their names?
3. How to get the statuses of tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was most annoyed by the same issue.  So I wrote this in C# to solve it:

I would get the Length of the file that the image refers to, then

```
            if (b.Length == 610) status = "Pass";
            if (b.Length == 1016) status = "Fail";
            if (b.Length == 353) status = "Inconclusive";
```

So if the file it refers to is 610 in length, then pass, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The HTML format of the exported logs is not intended to be parsed. If you want to parse exported logs, you need to use the XML format:

```
Log["SaveResultsAs"] ("PathToMyResultsXMLFile", lsXML);
```

Here is a sample snippet of the generated log file:

```
<Node name="message 0">
  <Prp name="date" type="D" value="41012.4210564815"/>
  <Prp name="priority" type="I" value="300"/>
  <Prp name="owner id" type="I" value="-1"/>
  <Prp name="color" type="I" value="-252645136"/>
  <Prp name="id" type="I" value="0"/>
  <Prp name="bkcolor" type="I" value="-252645136"/>
  <Prp name="message" type="S" value="This is a usual message"/>
  <Prp name="picture" type="S" value=""/>
  <Prp name="link" type="S" value=""/>
  <Prp name="unit id" type="I" value="0"/>
  <Prp name="remarks" type="S" value=""/>
  <Prp name="type" type="I" value="0"/>
  <Prp name="line no" type="I" value="2"/>
  <Prp name="child index" type="I" value="-1"/>
</Node>
```

The order of messages is specified by the '**id**' field and the type of a message is demoted by the '**type**' field.

```
0 - Message
1 - Event
2 - Warning
3 - Error
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't agree that this format is not intended to be parsed. According to TestComplete documentation http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/10992/ "Using the given scheme, we can parse the XML files containing the exported results in the desired manner. To perform this, you can use any XML parser."

Also, the HTML log format is lot more readable that the XML-s one, which is kind of strange. And I don't see any benefit from using that pseudo-XML as the export result consists from tons of files, just like HTML one does.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this topic. I believe that this is an issue in the documentation and this format (Unpacked Storage) should not be described as recommended for parsing. I am going to report this as an issue to SmartBear.

Comment: BTW, what exactly information you want to get while parsing logs? If you just need to get summary information on the current project test execution, you can find a sample script demonstrating how get it here: http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/9047/

Comment: I want to get this info about each test: its name, status, duration and the error message.
As I understood, the script you've mentioned will output a tree of results, but I need a plain view. P.S. currently I parse logs using powershell.

Comment: I think that it should not be very difficult to modify the script to make it generate plain results instead of a tree. I used to use this script to generate brief test report and then send it via e-mail at the end of a test execution (in the last test item). Unfortunately, I never saw a PowerShell version of this script.